# Javascript EventSource keeps reconnecting to SSE endpoint (in php)

Tags: javascript, php, server-sent-events

I am experiencing weird problem and not sure if this is expected behaviour.

I am trying to implement a super-simple proof-of-concept with SSE and a PHP script.

PHP file `sse.make-segment-snapshots.php`:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    $time = date('r');
    echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
    flush();
}

echo "data: END-OF-STREAM" . "\n\n";
flush();
```

Here's my JS/jquery code:

```
$('.btn-snap-all').on('click', function () {
      const source = new EventSource('sse.make-segment-snapshots.php');
      const listener = function (event) {
           if(typeof event.data !== 'undefined'){
                console.log(event.data);
           }
      };
      source.addEventListener('open', listener, false);
      source.addEventListener('message', listener, false);
      source.addEventListener('error', listener, false);

      return false;
});
```

However, instead of calling the endpoint once and running it with status 200, the page seemingly keeps reconnecting to it indefinitely:

[image]

Is this kind of behaviour expected or am I misreading something here?

Comment: The default behaviour of the EventSource connection is to terminate and for the client to reconnect. Typically you would use an infinite loop on the server so that the client connects once and receives data as an when the server has data to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment above - to avoid that constant disconnect/reconnect that you have experienced one would typically create an infinite loop on the server and send data back from within that loop every so often.
The following single page script demonstrates how you would initialise the `EventSource` connection when clicking a button that sends the request to the server. The server then proceeds to enter the infinite loop and send the data on a pre-determined schedule based upon a simple variable `$sleep`

```
<?php
    
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='GET' && isset( $_GET['task'] ) && $_GET['task']=='sse' ){
        ob_clean();
        
        function sse( $evtname='iss', $data=null, $retry=1000 ){
            if( !is_null( $data ) ){
                echo "event:".$evtname."\r\n";
                echo "retry:".$retry."\r\n";
                echo "data:" . json_encode( $data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT );
                echo "\r\n\r\n";
            }
        }
        
        header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache');


        $evt='EXPERIMENTS';
        $sleep=5;
        
        
        // create an infinite loop so that the client does not disconnect and reconnect every N seconds
        // the loop should be used to perhaps query a database, interrogate equipment sensors or fetch data 
        // from a remote API or whatever ...
        while( true ){
    
            $payload=array_merge( $_GET, array(
                'time'  =>  date('r')
            ));
            
            // send the data back to EventSource client
            call_user_func( 'sse', $evt, $payload );
            
            // Send output
            if( @ob_get_level() > 0 ) for( $i=0; $i < @ob_get_level(); $i++ ) @ob_flush();
            @flush();
            
            // wait for defined period before repeating infinite loop
            sleep( $sleep );
        }
        exit();
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>sse experiments</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type='button' class='btn-snap-all' value='Click me to begin SSE Experiment' />
        <input type='button' name='quit' value='Quit' />
        <output></output>
        
        <script>
            let evtsource;
            let output=document.querySelector('output');
            
            
            document.querySelector('[type="button"].btn-snap-all').addEventListener('click',e=>{
                let url=`${location.href}?task=sse`;
                
                evtsource = new EventSource( url, { withCredentials:false } );
                evtsource.addEventListener( 'EXPERIMENTS', e=>{
                    console.log( e.data );
                    let div=document.createElement('div');
                        div.textContent=e.data.toString();
                        
                    output.appendChild( div )
                });     
            });
            document.querySelector('[type="button"][name="quit"]').addEventListener('click',e=>{
                if( typeof evtsource == 'object' && evtsource instanceof EventSource ){
                    evtsource.close();
                    evtsource=null;
                    output.innerHTML='<h1>Goodbye</h1>';
                    return true;
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```